# Caching of PROPFIND requests?

Tags: caching, alfresco, webdav

Are there any standard technologies for implementing caching for WebDAV *PROPFIND* requests? Yes, these requests are obviously dynamic, but for a server under high load, the PROPFIND requests are often returning the exact same responses for hundreds of users. It would be nice to allow a minimal amount of caching, even for just a few seconds, as it will result in much lower load.

The repository in question is Alfresco, but in fact this question applies to any WebDAV repository. We are using Apache in front of Alfresco. Mature technology such as mod_cache is not usable because it only caches GET requests.

Comment: Can you solve it in the application? Application cache may be easier than a http cache, in this case.

Comment: In theory yes. Alfresco is open source, even the Enterprise Edition, and I even know where the code is for handling PROPFIND requests. However, I'd prefer to use a front end technology at the Apache level before it reaches Alfresco. Apache is so much nimbler than Alfresco. There is another reason to avoid extending the code: it jeopardizes the support contract.

Answer (score 0):

Does Alfresco support ctag's (like etags, but for a collection)? If so you should be able to key a front end cache on that, in the same way that etags are used by proxies to determine whether to return cached GET content.